# maven repackage module to resolve dependency conflict

Tags: java, maven, conflict

I have one project with 2 modules like below:

```
parent
├── SDK module 
└── service module
```

service module depends on SDK module. SDK module must depend on httpClient 3.x, but service module must depend on httpClient 4.x.

I know spring has one repackaged cglib. So I want repackage httpClient 3.x to SDK module to solve this.

Anyone know how to do this?(Maybe spring-boot:repackage?)

Comment: You can define the httpclient 4.X in service module but I assume that will fail in the end cause the service module has a dependency to SDK module not without a reason so it uses some parts of SDK module...So the question is why not using httpClient 3.x in service module? Or upgrading the SDK module ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Some time ago, I import someone's SDK code to my project. The SDK use some classes only in httpClient 3.x . It waste lots of time to copy out source code to upgrade. So I want find out one elegant way for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, in a service under development, I would like to avoid conflicting dependencies as much as possible.

If that's really not in an individual's hands you can make use of `<exclusions>` in your pom dependency declaration to avoid conflicting versions. Just trying, a sample around it would be like :-

**`SDKModule/pom.xml`**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version><!--just an example-->
</dependency>
```

**`ServiceModule/pom.xml`**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>some-group-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>sdk-module</artifactId>
    <version>some.version</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!--This adds an exclusive version of httpclient not included via sdk-module-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The maven auto excludes httpClient 3.x in service module. But there will have runtime exception because some code in SDK module can not find the class or method only in httpClient 3.x.